# Deserialize different json documents to the same object structure

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, deserialization

I'm looking for the best approach for such scenario:

I'd like to create WebApi which returns to the client some object like:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "name1",
   type: "type1"
}
```

I can retrieve such data from different data providers (document dbs) which can have different data structures like:

First source:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "name1",
   type: "type1"
}
```

Second source:

```
{
   productId: 1,
   productName: "product",
   productType: "type"
}
```

Third source:

```
{
   itemId: 1,
   itemName: "name",
   itemType: "type"
}
```

What will be the best approach to make it easy to extend with next data providers? I'd like to add that I was thinking about JSON.NET lib as always. So I believe I'm looking for examples of different json mappings depend on data providers? Anyone can help with some example? Let me add also that it's just 'read-only' scenario, so I mean that WebApi calls different dbs => deserialize to some object => eventually manipulates on the object itself => send over http.

Comment: I would simply use a mapping from each provider's result to your own reusable mapping, even if the data looks similar. Anything generic you will try to make is bound to break at the next new provider.

Comment: Best think to do would be IMO to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Automapper and three different dtos would be the most correct way imo. But if you want to do it a really simple way you could just create a single class with all the different properties and have corresponding properties use the same backing variable

```
class Item
{
    string _id;

    public string id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    public string productId
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
    public string itemId
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    string _name;

    public string name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public string productName
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public string itemName
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    string _type;

    public string type
    {
        get
        {
            return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
        }
    }
    public string productType
    {
        get
        {
            return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
        }
    }
    public string itemType
    {
        get
        {
            return _type;
        }
        set
        {
            _type = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more possible way to do that is use [serialization settings](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm) with custom [contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) object which overrides [ResolvePropertyName](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_ResolvePropertyName.htm) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoMapper to solve this problem.

http://automapper.org/

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Try the sample below

```
    public class ReturnObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    public class Source1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }
    public class Source2
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string ProductType { get; set; }
    }
    public class Source3
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ItemType { get; set; }
    }
```

AutoMapper Profile

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        //Same properties
        CreateMap<Source1, ReturnObject>();

        //Difference properties
        CreateMap<Source2, ReturnObject>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ProductId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ProductName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ProductType));
        CreateMap<Source3, ReturnObject>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ItemId))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ItemName))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(f => f.ItemType));
    }
}
```

Comment: So the thing is that I'd like to avoid defining those 'SourceX' entities. and instead of that deserialize directly from documentdb to ReturnObject